# pandas combine two columns with null values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nonetype

I have a df with two columns and I want to combine both columns ignoring the NaN values. The catch is that sometimes both columns have NaN values in which case I want the new column to also have NaN. Here's the example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'foodstuff':['apple-martini', 'apple-pie', None, None, None], 'type':[None, None, 'strawberry-tart', 'dessert', None]})

df
Out[10]:
foodstuff   type
0   apple-martini   None
1   apple-pie   None
2   None    strawberry-tart
3   None    dessert
4   None    None
```

I tried to use `fillna` and solve this :

```
df['foodstuff'].fillna('') + df['type'].fillna('')
```

and I got :

```
0      apple-martini
1          apple-pie
2    strawberry-tart
3            dessert
4                   
dtype: object
```

The row 4 has become a blank value. What I want in this situation is a NaN value since both the combining columns are NaNs.

```
0      apple-martini
1          apple-pie
2    strawberry-tart
3            dessert
4            None       
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Use [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) on one column with the fill values being the other column:

```
df['foodstuff'].fillna(df['type'])
```

The resulting output:

```
0      apple-martini
1          apple-pie
2    strawberry-tart
3            dessert
4               None
```

Comment: This only works because of the rather unrealistic example provided, in which there's always at least a None per row.

Comment: @kilgoretrout I find it works even when both columns contain null value

Comment: Is there any option to remove '`type` column after `fillna` in the same line.? ie by avoiding another 'drop` statement

Comment: TypeError: "value" parameter must be a scalar, dict or Series, but you passed a "Series"

Answer (score 7):

you can use the [`combine`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.combine.html) method with a `lambda`:

```
df['foodstuff'].combine(df['type'], lambda a, b: ((a or "") + (b or "")) or None, None)
```

`(a or "")` returns `""` if a is `None` then the same logic is applied on the concatenation (where the result would be `None` if the concatenation is an empty string).

Answer (score 4):

- `fillna` both columns together
- `sum(1)` to add them
- `replace('', np.nan)`

---

```
df.fillna('').sum(1).replace('', np.nan)

0      apple-martini
1          apple-pie
2    strawberry-tart
3            dessert
4                NaN
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 3):

*If you deal with columns that contain something where the others don't and vice-versa*, a one-liner that does well the job is

```
>>> df.rename(columns={'type': 'foodstuff'}).stack().unstack()
         foodstuff
0    apple-martini
1        apple-pie
2  strawberry-tart
3          dessert
```

... which solution also generalises well if you have multiple columns to "intricate", as long as you can define your `~.rename` mapping. The intention behind such renaming is to create duplicates that `~.stack().unstack()` will then process for you.

As explained, this solution only suits configuration with orthogonal columns, i.e. columns that never are simultaneously valued.

Comment: In my case pd.DataFrame.stack() does the column combination. `unstack` uncombines them.

Answer (score 2):

You can always fill the empty string in the new column with None

```
import numpy as np

df['new_col'].replace(r'^\s*$', np.nan, regex=True, inplace=True)
```

Complete code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'foodstuff':['apple-martini', 'apple-pie', None, None, None], 'type':[None, None, 'strawberry-tart', 'dessert', None]})

df['new_col'] = df['foodstuff'].fillna('') + df['type'].fillna('')

df['new_col'].replace(r'^\s*$', np.nan, regex=True, inplace=True)

df
```

output:

```
    foodstuff   type    new_col
0   apple-martini   None    apple-martini
1   apple-pie   None    apple-pie
2   None    strawberry-tart strawberry-tart
3   None    dessert dessert
4   None    None    NaN
```

Comment: A general solution should provide also zero replacement values for numeric data types (`.fillna(default_str_or_val)`)

Answer (score 1):

With [`combine_first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html) you can fill null values in one column with non-null values from another column:

```
In [3]: df['foodstuff'].combine_first(df['type'])
Out[3]: 
0      apple-martini
1          apple-pie
2    strawberry-tart
3            dessert
4               None
```

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the non zero values with column names like:

```
df1= df.replace(1, pd.Series(df.columns, df.columns))
```

Afterwards, replace 0's with empty string and then merge the columns like below:

```
f = f.replace(0, '')
f['new'] = f.First+f.Second+f.Three+f.Four
```

Refer the full code below:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Second':[0,1,0,0],'First':[1,0,0,0],'Three':[0,0,1,0],'Four':[0,0,0,1], 'cl': ['3D', 'Wireless','Accounting','cisco']})
df2=pd.DataFrame({'pi':['Accounting','cisco','3D','Wireless']})
df1= df.replace(1, pd.Series(df.columns, df.columns))
f = pd.merge(df1,df2,how='right',left_on=['cl'],right_on=['pi'])
f = f.replace(0, '')
f['new'] = f.First+f.Second+f.Three+f.Four
```

`df1`:

```
In [3]: df1                                                                                                                                                                              
Out[3]: 
   Second  First  Three  Four          cl
0       0  First      0     0          3D
1  Second      0      0     0    Wireless
2       0      0  Three     0  Accounting
3       0      0      0  Four       cisco
```

`df2`:

```
In [4]: df2                                                                                                                                                                              
Out[4]: 
           pi
0  Accounting
1       cisco
2          3D
3    Wireless
```

Final DataFrame `f` will be:

```
In [2]: f                                                                                                                                                                                
Out[2]: 
   Second  First  Three  Four          cl          pi     new
0          First                       3D          3D   First
1  Second                        Wireless    Wireless  Second
2                 Three        Accounting  Accounting   Three
3                        Four       cisco       cisco    Four
```

Answer (score 0):

We can make this problem even more complete and have a universal solution for this type of problem.

The key things in there are that we wish to join a group of columns together but just ignore `NaN`s.

Here is my answer:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'foodstuff':['apple-martini', 'apple-pie', None, None, None], 
               'type':[None, None, 'strawberry-tart', 'dessert', None],
              'type1':[98324, None, None, 'banan', None],
              'type2':[3, None, 'strawberry-tart', np.nan, None]})
```

[image]

```py
df=df.fillna("NAN")
df=df.astype('str')
df["output"] = df[['foodstuff', 'type', 'type1', 'type2']].agg(', '.join, axis=1)
df['output'] = df['output'].str.replace('NAN, ', '')
df['output'] = df['output'].str.replace(', NAN', '')
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you initialize your DataFrame with NaNs for missing values rather than None, you can use [Series.add()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.add.html) to fill NaN values on the fly when adding the columns together.

Example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'foodstuff':['apple-martini', 'apple-pie', np.NaN, np.NaN, np.NaN], 
'type':[np.NaN, np.NaN, 'strawberry-tart', 'dessert', np.NaN]})

df['foodstuff'].add(df['type'], fill_value = '')
```

Result:

```
0      apple-martini
1          apple-pie
2    strawberry-tart
3            dessert
4                NaN
```

This also works nicely for adding numerical columns that have some NaN values, as it allows you to add a number to a NaN value and get the number. Example:

```
df_test_nums = pd.DataFrame({'left_numbers':[1, 1, np.NaN, 3.7, 2.4], 
'right_numbers':[4, np.NaN, np.NaN, 2.7, 9.4]})
print(df_test_nums)
```

Result:

```
   left_numbers  right_numbers
0           1.0            4.0
1           1.0            NaN
2           NaN            NaN
3           3.7            2.7
4           2.4            9.4
```

Adding these columns together so that the sum of a number and a NaN value will be the number:

```
df_test_nums['left_numbers'].add(
    df_test_nums['right_numbers'], fill_value = 0)
```

Result:

```
0     5.0
1     1.0
2     NaN
3     6.4
4    11.8
```

Compare this to the use of the + operator, which converts the sum of NaN and a number into NaN:

```
df_test_nums['left_numbers'] + df_test_nums['right_numbers']
```

Result:

```
0     5.0
1     NaN
2     NaN
3     6.4
4    11.8
```

For operations that involve multiple columns, a more elegant approach is available via `df.sum()`.

```
print(df_test_nums[
          ['left_numbers', 'right_numbers']].sum(
              axis=1, min_count = 1))
```

output:

```
0     5.0
1     1.0
2     NaN
3     6.4
4    11.8
```

Note that, if min_count is set to 0 (the default), the 3rd row will equal 0, since that's the default output when values consisting only of NaNs are added together. (See the df.sum() documentation for more information.)